# Why isn't "I had to" contracted to "I'd to" unlike other auxiliary usage of the verb "had"?

Tags: contractions, auxiliary-verbs

We say "I had to leave," but not "I'd to leave." Why? This is also unlike other auxiliary usage of the verb "had" (e.g. in past perfect tense), so the difference is more nuanced than the *had* being an auxiliary verb or not; why is this not contracted like other auxiliary usage of the verb?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149765/discussion-on-question-by-nayfaan-why-isnt-i-had-to-contracted-to-id-to-un); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

"Had" in "I had to leave" is *not* an auxiliary verb. It can even be used with an auxiliary, e.g. "I have had to leave", "I might have to leave".

And it always (at least in my dialect) has the full "cat" vowel, never a schwa.

Comment: +1 It's not contractable.

Answer (score 4):

Question: We say "I had to leave," but not "I'd to leave." Why? This is also unlike other auxiliary usage* of the verb "had" (e.g. in past perfect tense), so the difference is more nuanced than the had being an auxiliary verb or not; why is this not contracted like other auxiliary usage of the verb?

Answer: *had* is not an auxiliary there. It is the main verb in the idiom: have to do something.

The past perfect tense of this usage would be:

"We'd had to leave earlier than they thought".

In the sentence above, "had" is the auxiliary and the second one is the past participle of "have".

[By the way, I am not dealing here with the British usage as given in the comments but do agree with Edwin and Fumble Fingers re I'd to [verb] for BrE.]

Comment: 'Must' is a modal (auxiliary) in 'I must do something'; 'have to' like 'used to' is considered a semi-modal by some.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth **Yes, but even so. it is not an auxiliary** here. And anyway, I already **said** I agree with you.

Comment: Yes. It's a verb, and -- more importantly for contraction rules -- it's **stressed.** Only unstressed syllables are contracted. The thought seems to be that if you can dispense with the vowel, you don't need the rest either.

Comment: 'Answer: had is not an auxiliary there. It is the main verb in the idiom: _have to do something_.' Apparent implication: auxiliaries don't contract. Counterexample: 'He's to leave on Thursday.' formal, but doubtless acceptable in the US as well as the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nope, I didn't say auxiliaries don't contract. You are saying that. He's to leave on Thursday. does  not contain an auxiliary. He is=main verb. Otherwise, there would only be an auxiliary and you can't do a declarative utterance with "to leave".

Comment: ''Had' is not a preposition either, but that doesn't answer the intended part of the question 'Why isn't "I had to" contracted to "I'd to" in the 'I had to attend court on Thursday' usage, be the usage a main verb or semi-modal?'